# Неверные вычисления в микроконтроллере

Tags: c, arm

На микроконтроллере 1986ВЕ93У таймер захватывает частоту и выполняет с ней математические преобразования. Проблемная часть преобразований выглядит следующим образом:

```
float KalmanCustom(float cur, float last, float kalcoeff)
{
    return cur * kalcoeff + (1.0 - kalcoeff) * last;
}

volatile float rawpressure;

void HandlePres()
{
    float frequency = ЗНАЧЕНИЕ_ИЗ_РЕГИСТРА;
    rawpressure = KalmanCustom(frequency, rawpressure, 0.005);    
}
```

Функция HandlePres - обработчик прерывания. Частота нормально записывается в переменную `frequency`. А с `rawpressure` наблюдаются проблемы. Привожу график, на котором синяя линия - `frequency`, оранжевая линия - переменная `rawpressure`, серая - тоже `rawpressure`, вычисленная на ПК. Оранжевая линия должна совпасть с серой, но это не так. Какие идеи?

Переменная `rawpressure` объявлена как `volatile`. Запись в неё осуществляет только этот обработчик прерывания. Остальные процессы только читают.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: есть подозрение, что математика на компе и процессоре немного разная (точность вычислений). Поищите в документации на проц, как повысить точность вычислений

Comment: А использование `Double` невозможно в вашем случае? Вот [тема](http://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread636371.html) с примером точности вычислений между `Float` и `Double`.

Comment: @KoVadim, обратите внимание, что переход между ступеньками плавный. Вряд ли дело в точности float. Но я почитаю об этом. Процессор не имеет математического сопроцессора, поэтому использование double сильно замедляет работу.

Comment: как раз я и увидел эти ступеньки. А это обычно говорит о том, что процессор немного округляет  результат - то есть, просто загрубляет.

Comment: Так а тип `float` на вашей платформе - это классический IEEE 754 32-битный `float`? Или все таки какой-то свой местечковый `float`?

Comment: В вычислении оранжевой линии участвовали все те измерения, которые показаны на синей линии? Т.е. вы считывали в хэндлере frequency, записывали его куда-то в память, вычисляли rawpressure и ... (вот тут поподробнее, кто и как переписывал эти данные)

Comment: @avp, нет, не все. Обработчик прерывания срабатывает с частотой 45 кГц. А данные на ПК передавались раз в секунду по RS-232. Но если бы в переменную frequency попадали какие-то выбивающиеся значения, то хотя бы несколько раз их тут было видно. На остальные вопросы пока не могу ответить.

Comment: прерывания при входе в обработчик запрещал? может просто вложенные проскакивают, отсюда и гонка...

Comment: Странно, но факт: когда я заменил 1 на 1.0, все заработало.

Comment: Разве в выражении все операнды не должны приводиться к самому сложному типу?